# Conditional PHP inside form email body

Tags: php, forms

No need to be rude everyone. I really wasn't that far off, I just had my syntax wrong, as was politely indicated in the accepted answer. Isn't that the point of an open forum such as this? I have learned a lot on the site so thank you to those who are humble and not entitled. Original question below.

---

I have a form with many fields, but not all are required. I am no PHP wizard, but I wrote the following code (which doesn't work) to try to remove the empty fields from my form email.

```
$body = "
<h4>".$name." </h4>
<span'>is coming to ".$coming."</span>
<br/>
"if isset($name2){"
<h4'>".$name2." </h4>
<span'>is coming to ".$coming2."</span>
<br/>
"} ......... and so forth........
```

I realize this is poor logic, so have atter..

Comment: Email body? Where? Form? Where? That `if` syntax is wrong. Condition should be between parentheses.

Comment: things to look into the php manual: `how output a string`, `instruction separation`, `syntax of "if"`.

Comment: right. this is obviously a snippet of the full code. i know i have to email the body. thanks though

Comment: What in the world is this?.  Read, learn, and then code.  Code like yours give PHP it's ugly reputation,  not for being a bad language, but for the way anybody uses it, and call it programming.

Comment: thanks for the constructive criticism. you're a real gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not properly concatenating the string. It should look like:

```
$body = "
<h4>".$name." </h4>
<span'>is coming to ".$coming."</span>
<br/>";

if (isset($name2)){
 //note the .= operator for appending (concatenating) to the string
  $body .="        
  <h4>".$name2." </h4>
  <span'>is coming to ".$coming2."</span>
  <br/>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your polite answer. It worked. As I suspected, I wasn't that far off.

Answer (score 0):

```
$body = "
<h4>".$name." </h4>
<span>is coming to ".$coming."</span>
<br/>
".(isset($name2) ?"
<h4>".$name2." </h4>
<span>is coming to ".$coming2."</span>
<br/>
" : "" ).//and so forth
```

You should use ternary operator for creating "if conditions" in Function Parameters or string concat.